# Iterating through lines without passing an offset

Tags: c

I can use the following function to iterate through some text and grab it line by line:

```
int nextline(char * text, unsigned int * start_at, char * buffer) {
    /*
    it will return the length of the line if there is a line, or -1 otherwise.
    it will fill the character buffer with the line
    and return where the pointer has 'finished' for that line so it can be used again
    */
    int i;
    char c;

    if (*start_at > strlen(text)) return -1;

    for (i=0; (c = * (text + *start_at + i)); i++) {
        buffer[i] = c;
        if (c == '\0') break;
        if (c == '\n') {
            buffer[i+1] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    * start_at = * start_at + i + 1;

    return i;

}
```

However, this function requires passing in an offset, for example:

```
char * longtext = "This is what I went to do\nWhen I came over\nto the place and thought that\nhere we go again";
char buffer[60];
unsigned int line_length, start_at=0;

for (int i=1; (line_length = nextline(longtext, &start_at, buffer)) != -1; i++)
    printf("Line %2d. %s\n", i, buffer);
```

How would I write an equivalent function where it "remembers" where the cursor is and I don't need to keep passing it back into the function?

Comment: That looks like you're reinventing a limited version of `strtok_r()`? Could use plain `strtok()`, but its use of a global to store state is generally considered a misfeature...

Comment: Or use [`fmemopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) and `fgets()`...

Comment: `strsep()` is another option, though it's not POSIX like the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass an offset, you could implement this by using a `static` variable inside of the function to keep track of the current offset.  Doing so has disadvantages, however.

Suppose you were to use a `static` variable for the offset.  You then process a complete string.  Now what happens when you want to process another string?  You need to somehow tell the function to "start over".  Also, suppose you wanted to process two separate strings alternately, i.e. you call the function first on one string, then the other, then back to the first.  The internal state wouldn't be able to manage that.

The best way to manage these types of issues is to do exactly what you're doing now: passing the address of a variable to keep track of the state.  That way it's up to the calling function to keep track of the current state while your `nextline` function is stateless.

There are a number of older functions in the standard library that use internal state that were superseded by newer function that don't.  One notable example is `strtok`.  This function uses internal state to tokenize a string.  The POSIX function `strtok_r` was created later that receives an additional parameter for state.

So keep your function the way it is.  It's generally considered better design to not depend on internal state.

Comment: thanks for this response. It seems a bit clunky that I need to keep track of three variables for such a simple function. Is that a common thing in C? Or is there an issue with my code above (as you can tell, I'm trying to learn the language!)

Comment: "Is that a common thing in C?" -- yes, and that is a good thing. C doesn't come with training-wheels. It is a low-level language. There are no internal safety checks. That's what makes C so blazingly fast, but also places the complete responsibility on the programmer to make sure it is done correctly.